# Google fusion table where clause

Tags: javascript, google-maps, where-clause, google-fusion-tables

I'm developing an app which allows user to select the region on the map. On click of the map I'm storing that region's state and country in two separate arrays. I want to apply a query on fusion table which gives me the data for only selected states and countries.

I have tried the following two separate queries for country and state selection.

```
var selectState = {
                    select: 'kml_4326',
                    from: 420419,
                    where: "'name_1' IN ('Montana','Nevada')"
                };

var selectCountry = {
                    select: 'kml_4326',
                    from: 420419,
                    where: "'name_0' IN ('Canada','Russia')"
                };
```

Both queries works fine when I apply separately to the fusion table layer. I want to merge these two queries. I tried the following for merging but not working:

```
 var selectStateAndCountry = {
                        select: 'kml_4326',
                        from: 420419,
                        where: "'name_0' IN ('Canada','Russia') AND 'name_1' IN  ('Montana','Nevada')"
                    };
```

Please suggest me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query, but your query didn't match any row(neither Montana nor Nevada are located in Canada or Russia).

This Query would return results:

```
{
    select: 'kml_4326',
    from: 420419,
    where: "'name_0' IN ('United States of America','Canada') " +
           " AND 'name_1' IN  ('Montana','Nevada')"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dr.Molle. I want a query which will select some states and some country. Like in above query I want whole USA and Canada selected, and some states from other countries.

Comment: It's not possible, this would require a `OR` -clause which currently is not supported in FusionTable-SQL . What you can do: Use 2 separate layers, 1 for the countries and 1 for the states

Comment: Can you suggest any other solution/method for this?

Comment: I've added a suggestion to my comment above